# MVC .NetCore Uploading images using IMAGESHARP and displaying in an array

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, colors

I have an upload script that uploads and saves images to a folder.

PROBLEM:
I want to add different colour schemes to the images and display to the user in an array or images.

here is my  script

```
using (Image<Rgba32> image = SixLabors.ImageSharp.Image.Load(Path.Combine(path, pic.FileName)))
{  
    image.Mutate(ctx => ctx
         .Resize(image.Width / 2, image.Height / 2)
         .Polaroid()); //Add colour format

    image.Save(fileName);// .Save to disk    
}
```

`.Polaroid()` above is a colour format, others abound e.g. `.GrayScale()` , `.Glow()` , `.OilPaint` etc (I want to give up to 10 options to the user)

My question is thus

1. How do I loop through each one, one by one then assign them to a variable ?
2. Or would it be better to save them to disk and then retrieve and display back to the user ? (Bearing in mind option 2 could be resource intensive)

thank you

here is a far fetched code

```cs
using (Image<Rgba32> image = SixLabors.ImageSharp.Image.Load(Path.Combine(path, pic.FileName)))
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
    {
        image.Mutate(
            ctx => ctx
            .Resize(image.Width / 2, image.Height / 2)
            .Polaroid());

        image.Save(fileName);// .


        // repeat the above 10  times removing the resize option e.g. 
        // Adding a change of filename value, so you get the value 10 times. 
        // Which I feel might be resourse intensive if heavily hit by web users

        fileName = Path.Combine(he.WebRootPath + "/uploads/" + "/" + user, Path.GetFileName("2" + pic.FileName));

        image.Mutate(
            ctx => ctx
            .OilPaint()); // GIVES YOU OIL PAINT FORMAT

        image.Save(fileName); // .
        fileName = Path.Combine(he.WebRootPath + "/uploads/" + "/" + user, Path.GetFileName("3" + pic.FileName));

        image.Mutate(
            ctx => ctx
            .Grayscale()); // GIVES YOU gray scale formattinng

        image.Save(fileName); // .
    }
}
```

Comment: Show effort, post what you tried (incl. errors) to make it work yourself first.

Comment: To be honest, I dont have a clue. I was thinking of either one repeating the code for each colour format, as I have edited it above

Comment: Posting that edit-update may help.. lets wait for the cavalry to help you out on your problem. End of review. Enjoy SO ;-)

Comment: Please stop adding the incorrect `ImageProcessor` tag to your questions. I've had to remove it twice now. Read the tag description. It is nothing to do with `ImageSharp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little odd. While ImageSharp is your target here, you're essentially asking several questions about the best practise for serving images to an end user.

In answer to the ImageSharp specific part. `Clone()` is your friend here.

```cs
using (var image = Image.Load(Path.Combine(path, pic.FileName)))
{  
    // First resize the image. No point repeating it for each clone. 
    image.Mutate(x => x.Resize(image.Width / 2, image.Height / 2));

    // Now clone the image and apply the effect.
    // If you are offering options perhaps a switch statement would be a good idea.
    using (var clone = image.Clone(x => x.Polaroid())))
    {  
        clone.Save(fileName); // .Save to disk
    }

    // Let's clone it again. The original image is untouched.
    using (var clone2 = image.Clone(x => x.OilPaint())))
    {  
        clone2.Save(fileName2); // .Save to disk
    }    
}
```

I would always recommend saving to disk and let the static file handler serve the images. You should be implementing some sort of caching mechanism also.

Comment: thanks James and I must commend you for an awesome product. I am getting an error, which is

Comment: Error message is: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\ehi\OneDrive\Documents\MEGAsync\IT Projects\wwwroot\uploads\lone\BJQC1706.JPG' because it is being used by another process.

Comment: It's probably one drive locking the file as it synchronizes it to the cloud.

Comment: apparently not, I stopped both onedrive and mega sync, and still getting the same error, I also tried using image.Dispose(); and didnt work. I am starting a new thread

Comment: Disposing the image has nothing to do with the error, in fact the error has nothing to do with the library, Something else is locking the file.